# Is it possible to find out what request sended in Chrome Inspecter?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to find out what request, such as `XMLHttpRequest`, called in javascript? Is there anyway to find out? In   Chrome Inspecter or inject some codes to find with chrome extensions?
Thanks!

Comment: Uhm, have you checked "Network" tab?

Comment: Are you talking about through the dev tools or through JavaScript?  If you just want to view it yourself for a site, press F12, then click the Network tab, then look at the bottom for XHR and click that.

Comment: To Qantas 94 Heavy, both. To zerkms, I have not. I will try now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Chrome Developer Tools Network panel to view captured network traffic. Open the dev tools and select the Network panel. You may need to enable logging of XMLHttpRequests by opening the settings by clicking in the gear icon on the bottom right corner of the dev tools. Scroll down the list and make sure that the Log XMLHttpRequest option is checked.